# Proof verification: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, estimation

I'm having issues forming the discussion part of the proof because I am not sure if I am coming up with the right estimation. Is this an appropriate way of coming up with an estimation?

I wrote:

We want to show that $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists N>0$, $N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n>N \Longrightarrow |(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)-0|<\epsilon$. Then we will proceed by simplifying 
$$
\begin{split}
\sqrt{n^2+1}-n
 &= \left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right) \times
    \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\\
 &=\frac{n^2+1-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\\
 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}
\end{split}
$$
by using the conjugate. 
Now we will proceed by making an estimation, we see that $$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} \leq \frac{1}{n+1},
\quad \text{where } n > 1.
$$
So let $\frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon$ Then by multiplying both sides by $(n+1)$ and dividing both sides by $\epsilon$ we have $\frac{1}{\epsilon}< n+1$. Now we want to subtract 1 from both sides and we arrive at $\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1 < n$. We will choose $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$ for when $n>1$

I'm new to formulating proofs with rigor. Thanks for your help.

Comment: why would someone downvote this legitimate question? SMH

Comment: You did very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did well.

A perhaps simpler way is to observe that $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n>2n$, so
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}<\frac{1}{2n}
$$
and we just need to take as $N$ any integer such that
$$
N>\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}
$$
(which exists by the Archimedean property). As soon as $n>N>1/(2\varepsilon)$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}<\frac{1}{2n}<\frac{1}{2N}<\varepsilon
$$

Comment: I appreciate your clarity. In terms of what I can have as a constant multiple to my estimation, does it matter what value I choose? I'm assuming that I would choose a constant that is like yours one that is in $\mathbb{Q}$ or some value greater than $0$ that belongs to $\mathbb{N}$ right? And one that is fairly small? I'm wondering intuitively what qualities should this constant have.

Comment: @dls No, it doesn't matter what upper bound you choose, so long as it leads you to the end. Happily for you, this kind of exercises will stop early.

Answer (score 4):

$$ n^2 < n^2 + 1 < \left( n + \frac{1}{2n} \right)^2 $$

Comment: May I ask for clarification for how you arrived at this inequality or why did you do what you did? I'm am interested in understanding how I can use this idea for other situations.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the template:

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given.

Choose $N= .... $ (Here is you choice of $N$ that depends on $\epsilon)$

Now, for $n > N $, show that your $N$ satisfies

$$ |a_n - L | < \epsilon $$

Just show your work backwards.